# How can I have multiple boxes of the same type?

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I want to store the same type of information in different boxes.
Example : One box would contain the tweets I liked, and another the tweets I retweeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create two separate stores in different directories.  This can be accomplished using the directory parameter of openStore.

```
_store1 = await openStore(directory: '/retweets');
_store2 = await openStore(directory: '/likedTweets');
```

Be aware that if you do this, you can't use relations between objects stored in separate stores using the built in relations.  Ex: You couldn't have any of your retweeted objects use a relation to any liked tweets.

To bypass that, you could use some unique ID to query the other store exactly like you would with a RDB

Comment: I have no need for relations, so this is perfect. Thanks !